# Showing that a Taylor series converges to $f(x)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I want to show that the Taylor series of the function  $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ converges to $f(x)$ itself. I have already found the Taylor series that represents $f(x)$ which is
$$1+ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(2(k-1))!}{2^{k-1}(k-1)! \cdot 2^k} \cdot \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Now I want to prove that this Taylor-Jet converges to the function $f(x)$ for $x>-\frac{1}{2}$. How would I now prove that the remainder converges to zero?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the error term of a Taylor-polynomial approximation to a function (often called the Lagrange remainder formula)?

Comment: It would be a Taylor-jet if it was truncated after a finite number of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Convergence to $\sqrt{1+x}$ for all $x > -1/2$ is not what you want, since the radius of convergence is $1$. Maybe you mean $-1/2 < x < 1/2$?

For $0 < r < 1$< the series is absolutely convergent when $|x| < r$ and has a positive value (check). Show the series multiplied by itself equals $1+x$ (do you know how to multiply absolutely convergent power series?), so the series has to be $\sqrt{1+x}$ by positivity.

Do you happen to know complex analysis?  Working with power series is often much simpler if you can rely on some complex analysis.